# Npgsql : how to get PQntuples?

Tags: npgsql

I'm trying to get the number of rows returned by a SELECT command.
RowAffected works only for insert, update and so on, but not for select.
PostgreSQL has the PQntuples() function but it doesn't exist in Npgsql and I can't get the answer out of any of the various versions of the Rows property (or Statement.Rows, or... ?).
Is there something I'm missing, or is it not possible at all ?
Thank you.
Nynn

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply count the rows yourself as you're processing them with NpgsqlDataReader? In other words, simply increment a counter every time you call NpgsqlDataReader.Read()...

Comment: I know it is obviously possible, but I sometimes prefer to know immediately the number of results, especially if the number of rows is huge... BTW I'm wondering: is PQntuples known before reading the 1st row, or only after reading the complete set ? To be tested !